# What does "find religion" mean here?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean **find it necessary**?

Large companies around the world in a variety of sectors are finding religion in getting smaller.

Source: https://edition.cnn.com/2021/11/12/investing/johnson-johnson-ge-toshiba-splits/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[finding religion](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20found%20religion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20found%20religion%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Che%20found%20religion%3B%2Cc0)** is a relatively recent expression to describe somebody that previously had no religious beliefs who takes up a new religion.

This journalist is using the expression to suggest that many big companies are taking up the (relatively new) idea of splitting into smaller companies, and they are making it an [article of faith](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/article-of-faith).

Comment: 'Kudlow 'seems to have found religion' on government spending' (_The Hill_, March 2021)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a lot of sense. I can guess what it means, but to me it reads like a journalist desperately trying to find a new way of saying something that is not actually very exciting.

It seems to mean that they are "hearing the word" or "being enlightened".

Answer (score 0):

Religion can mean

> a cause, principle, or system of beliefs held to with ardor and faith

(Definition #4 From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/religion))

So the article is saying that these companies are adopting the principle or beliefs in smaller organisations being more effective and the associated practice of creating smaller organisations.